# Time Enabled Polygon Shapefiles in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online, timeslider

I have a polygon shapefile with 150 features. The shapefile has 10 columns of data, each representing a year. I would like to do a simple time slider Choropleth in an AGOL map to explore changes in these values over the 10 years.

I transposed the shapefile so now I have 1500 features, each one representing a polygon in a given year. I am now able to make the layer 'time-enabled' and upload it AGOL. When loading the feature layer in to a map it **fails to render** due to the size of the dataset (1500 features). Is this the right approach? It seems inefficient to have a replica of the polygon geometry for every year.

I also feel like that it is unlikely that AGOL wouldn't be able to handle this kid of task and am sure I have seen examples where far larger quantities of data have been represented over time.

Comment: I've not tried it in AGOL, but I know in ArcMap time enabled layer had an option for time based on a single field or multiple fields. If you configured it correctly, you could set each feature with a begin date/time and an end date/time. If AGOL supports the same, it should allow you to go back to just the 150 features.  And documentation suggests hosted layer should support this capability if configured correctly https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-time.htm

Answer (score 3):

I would say the approach to uploading the 1500 feature file to AGOL is not, due to limitations [Is there a feature limit in ArcGIS Online?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012039)

> No a there is not a feature limit for Hosted Feature Layers. However, a limit is applied when adding features directly to the web map in ArcGIS Online. By default, there is a limit of 1,000 features when uploading a file (shapefile or CSV file) to a web map on ArcGIS Online. The 1,000 feature limit is a general limit enforced by ArcGIS Online to efficiently manage uploaded features. However, it is not a hard limit; therefore if the file being uploaded has more than 1,000 features, an error occurs or it causes performance issues.
>
> The features in the file are stored in the web map when the file is added to the web map. Therefore, adding a large amount of data to a web map causes the map to have a large file size. When the map is downloaded by a web browser, especially on a mobile device, it may take a significant amount of time. Performance of the web map varies depending on the browser used to view the map, so keeping the number of features to a minimum provides the best results.
>
> To upload a file beyond the feature limit set by ArcGIS Online, use feature services. Feature services are a more scalable way to publish features as it supports vector feature querying, visualization, and editing.

Your best option would be hosted layers. [Prerequisites to publish hosted layers](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/hosted-web-layers.htm)